# Getting sum of values of a column of a jtable

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans6.5

I want to get the sum of values of a column of the table on the click of a button, perform calculations, and then display results in the corresponding textfields.

I used the following code:-

```
    int delivery = Integer.parseInt(DELIVERYCHG.getText());

    int subtot = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= ITEMDETAILSTABLE.getRowCount(); i++) {
        String stot1 = (ITEMDETAILSTABLE.getValueAt(i, 4).toString());
        int stot = Integer.parseInt(stot1);
        subtot = subtot + stot;
    }

    SUBTOTAL.setText("" + subtot);

    int subtotanddelivery = subtot + delivery;
    int gst = (int) (0.18 * subtotanddelivery);
    int total = subtotanddelivery + gst;
    GST.setText("" + gst);
    TOTAL.setText("" + total)
```

But output showed a error like this:
    Exception in thread 
        "AWT-EventQueue-0" 
        java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
        5 >= 5.

How can it be resolved?

Comment: Change the loop condition to `i < ITEMDETAILSTABLE.getRowCount()`

Comment: Thank You...that worked.

Comment: use  String stot1 = (ITEMDETAILSTABLE.getValueAt(i, 3).toString());   it starts with 0  so use 3 instead of 3 ... it may also be a concern

Comment: @pawansharma Thank you but the issue has been resolved by changing <= with <. Actually I wanted value from 5th column. so  String stot1 = (ITEMDETAILSTABLE.getValueAt(i, 4).toString()) will be used

Comment: @janos Thanks...it worked and problem was solved.

Comment: @JoeC I dont know it is duplicate or not. But i found this problem in my own program, hence asked this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
int i = 0; i <= ITEMDETAILSTABLE.getRowCount(); i++
```

to

```
int i = 0; i < ITEMDETAILSTABLE.getRowCount(); i++
```

Indexes are counted from zero, so if 5 elements are in present, 4 is maximum index.